# Get extensions inside directory bash

Tags: bash, perl, directory

Im trying to get all the extensions in the directory passed as $1 parameter.
The problem is that Im getting extensions that are not inside $1. I use cd command to get into the directory in the first line but it seems that it does not work.

```
cd $1

 find . -type f | perl -ne 'print $1 if m/\.([^.\/]+)$/' | sort -u > $1extensions.txt
```

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"extension"*? To avoid going into sub directories with `find` you could also use the `maxdepth` option, e.g.: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f`

Comment: Is the `cd` performed in the same shell as `find`? Please provide a minimal directory structure and value for `$1` that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following Perl command:

```
perl -MList::Util=uniq -sE '
   chdir $dir; say for uniq map { /\.([^.\/]+)$/ ? $1 : () } grep -f, <*>;
' -- -dir="$1" > "$1"-extensions.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

There's obviously something you're not saying, because there's no bug in `find` that will list files outside of the specified directory, and there's no bug in your Perl program that will invent extensions.

```
$ find
.
./foo
./foo/a.good
./a.bad
./script

$ cat ./script
#!/bin/bash
cd $1
find . -type f | perl -ne 'print $1 if m/\.([^.\/]+)$/' | sort -u > $1extensions.txt

$ ./script foo

$ cat foo/fooextensions.txt
good
txt        <-- From the output file you created inside the directory in which you search.
```